# Requiredfieldvalidator with no postback (Only Javascript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I would like to know if it is possible to do requiredfieldvalidator purely in javascript.
I do not want my button click which processes the page to perform a postback, as postback completely resets my styling and there is too much to reload on ispostback.

I will however do the postback to the server to update SQL once all the fields have been completed.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="PurGradeUpdate" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline">
       <ContentTemplate>
          <telerik:RadComboBox ID="PURGrade" runat="server" Width="100" EmptyMessage=" ---" Font-Bold="true"></telerik:RadComboBox>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PurGradeValidate" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="PURGrade" ErrorMessage="!!!" Font-Italic="true" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue=" ---" EnableClientScript="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
       </ContentTemplate>
       <Triggers>
           <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="PURProduct" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
       </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel> 
<telerik:RadButton ID="PurCreate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" OnClientClicked="PerformValidation"></telerik:RadButton>
```

I have the above in an update panel as the comboboxes are populated via SQL read, based on other comboboxes selected index changes.

I would now like to call that "PerformValidation" on my process button click and here the validation must happen, and if not valid, display the errormessage.

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok man i checked it on my VS and this works for sure:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="PurGradeUpdate" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline">
       <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="PURGrade" runat="server" Width="100" Font-Bold="true"></asp:DropDownList>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PurGradeValidate" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="PURGrade" ErrorMessage="!!!" Font-Italic="true" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="---" EnableClientScript="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="PURProduct" runat="server" Width="100" Font-Bold="true"></asp:DropDownList>
       </ContentTemplate>
       <Triggers>
           <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="PURProduct" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
       </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel> 
<Asp:Button ID="PurCreate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></Asp:Button>
```

In aspx.cs file I added default value:

```
PURGrade.Items.Insert(0, "---");
```

So as i told you before you don't need to use custom JavaScript commands to validate on client side cuz asp required field validator runs on client side by default. The only think that can cause problems in your code is custom controls you use. Be sure that your combo box empty value is what is really added to the select list as a default value.

Comment: What happens now no matter what is in my comboboxes is: redirects to a new page displaying "true". Validators are thus not working...

Comment: @Killua Did you try changing AutoPostBack="false" to AutoPostBack="True"?

Comment: I changed my example to force validation from js so now validation should work.

Comment: I dont want autopostback=true as I dont want postback at all, just want the validators to display the error messages on all the required boxes via javascript, and once the page is validated, I will then postback etc. I can only try your edit on Friday as I am back on my dev PC then. Will let you know

Comment: I have just tried the above, it keeps returning true on a new page.
I have added a validator just to a textbox and left that blank as well, and still returns true. Don't know if there is something else I am missing. Looks like I may have to do each box manually in jscript before posting to the server.

Comment: @Killua I think you are trying to hard to do whats is already done by asp. I posted example code in which I replaced your custom controls with asp once and everything works properly (site is validated on client side)

Comment: it turns out it was working, but only on full post back - so I had to correct all of my ispostback to keep current styling..as lots of things change and are visible / not visible based on certain changes etc. So My styling has to be reloaded on each postback - wanted to avoid this as it is a lot of unnecessary code as I wanted no post back until clientvalidated. But I will make do with this. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: @Killua try to move your button PurCreate to the content template of your update panel and then check your validation. Here's an example <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398929(v=vs.100).aspx>

Comment: Its working now, but I have about 5 update panels, as soon as one is updated, the requiredfiled is set off and it displays the error message. Is there anyway of getting by that? Maybe have it in an update panel of its own with a fullpostback trigger? Or an asynchronous trigger being the PurCreate button? I quickly tried that but think my thinking may need some help with that one?

Comment: @Killua Im not sure if i understand you. You mean that other update panel cause  required field validation to trigger? Or maybe that validation message stays visible when you update other panel?

Comment: Yes, if any of the update panels are reloaded, the requiredfieldvalidator is also fired at the same time. I only want the validator to fire on the button click, and not everytime the partial postback is done in the update panels

Comment: @Killua ok so I think you will need to set CausesValidation = false on your update panels and/or controls other than button

Comment: Great, that sorted the problem out completely. Thank you :)